# Async queries with DB2 and .NET

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, db2

I'm trying to execute async queries against DB2 under .NET 4.7 on Windows 10 with VS2017 using the latest DB2 .NET Driver (v11.1 fixpack 3) I would expect some performance increase, but it seems that the async variant is not really async. Am I totally wrong? The performance of the async and sync variants are more or less identical. If I replace the queries with Task.Delay or other tasks, the async performs better.

I assume I either have wrong or too high expectations, that I'm not using the DB2 driver correctly for async or the DB2 driver is misconfigured.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using IBM.Data.DB2;
using System.Data;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Db2AsyncTest
{
   public class Program
   {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Warm up
            TestSync();
            TestAsync().Wait();
            TestSync();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    static async Task TestAsync()
    {
        var dt = DateTime.Now;
        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            tasks.Add(ExecuteAsync());
        }
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        var dt2 = DateTime.Now;
        var timeSpan = dt2 - dt;
        Console.WriteLine("Async Time: " + timeSpan.TotalMilliseconds);

    }

    static async Task ExecuteAsync()
    {
        using (var conn = new DB2Connection(""))
        {
            await conn.OpenAsync();
            var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE";
            var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
            var dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(reader);
        }
    }


    static void TestSync()
    {
        var dt = DateTime.Now;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            ExecuteSync();
        }
        var dt2 = DateTime.Now;
        var timeSpan = dt2 - dt;
        Console.WriteLine("Sync Time: " + timeSpan.TotalMilliseconds);

    }



    static void ExecuteSync()
    {
        using (var conn = new DB2Connection(""))
        {
            conn.Open();
            var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE";
            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            var dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(reader);
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: You state that you were expecting a perfomance increase. What do you mean by this? Are you expecting an async method to be faster than a non-async one? Because the point of async-await is to make apps more responsive by freeing up threads while waiting for I/O events. In a single threaded context it won't make a difference to overall execution time.

Comment: Good point. I was kind of expecting more throughput since the db-operations are very IO-bound. Maybe this is a wrong assumption?

Comment: Can you try increasing the sample size to, let's say, 1000 queries instead of 10? Perhaps the operations are too short lived to make a difference.

Comment: With 1000 queries, both take around 27 seconds. I am starting to suspect that the DB2 .NET driver might support some async operations, but that ExecuteReaderAsync etc are not implemented as sync.

Comment: Most DB Engines have a limit on the number of active connections and transactions they can handle. Sync/Async will not make any difference to DB performance at all. All you are doing is sleeping threads until the IO operation is complete so that threads can be used for more useful work, which could be another IO task, or something else. If you dont have anything else waiting for a thread to execute, then you wont see any benefit at all.

Comment: Thanks to both of you! I'll do a test with SQL Server as well, and report back.

Comment: Tested with SQL Server on Azure (Adventure Works), and changed SQL to "SELECT * FROM SalesLT.PRODUCT" and of course SqlConnection instead of DB2Connection. Async is working twice as fast as sync (50 queries take about 18s sync and 8,5 seconds async), and this leads me to believe that the DB2 driver has not implemented async completely.

Comment: Confirmation of not full async support from IBM here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.adonet.ref.doc/doc/r0070119.html